# Representing syntactically different terms in TPTP

Tags: syntax, theorem-proving, logic-programming, first-order-logic

I am having a look at first order logic theorem provers such as Vampire and E-Prover, and the TPTP syntax seems to be the way to go. I am more familiar with Logic Programming syntaxes such as Answer Set Programming and Prolog, and although I try refering to a detailed description of the [TPTP syntax](http://www.cs.miami.edu/~tptp/TPTP/TR/TPTPTR.shtml) I still don't seem to grasp how to properly distinguish between interpreted and non interpreted functor (and I might be using the terminology wrong).

Essentially, I am trying to prove a theorem by showing that no model acts as a counter-example. My first difficulty was that I did not expect the following logic program to be satisfiable.

```
fof(all_foo, axiom, ![X] : (pred(X) => (X = foo))).
fof(exists_bar, axiom, pred(bar)).
```

It is indeed satisfiable because nothing prevents `bar` from being equal to `foo`. So a first solution would be to insist that these two terms are distinct and we obtain the following unsatisfiable program.

```
fof(all_foo, axiom, ![X] : pred(X) => (X = foo)).
fof(exists_bar, axiom, pred(bar)).
fof(foo_not_bar, axiom, foo != bar).
```

The Techinal Report clarifies that different double quoted strings are different objects indeed, so another solution is to put quotes here and there, so as to obtain the following unsatisfiable program.

```
fof(all_foo, axiom, ![X] : (pred(X) => (X = "foo"))).
fof(exists_bar, axiom, pred("bar")).
```

I am happy not to have manually specify the inequality as that would obviously not scale to a more realistic scenario. Moving closer to my real situation, I actually have to handle composed terms, and the following program is unfortunately satisfiable.

```
fof(all_foo, axiom, ![X] : (pred(X) => (X = f("foo")))).
fof(exists_bar, axiom, pred(g("bar"))).
```

I guess `f("foo")` is not a term but the function `f` applied to the object `"foo"`. So it could potentially coincide with function `g`. Although a manual specification that `f` and `g` never coincide does the trick, the following program is unsatisfiable, I feel like I'm doing it wrong. And it probably wouldn't scale to my real setting with plenty of terms all to be interpreted as distinct when they are syntactically distinct.

```
fof(all_foo, axiom, ![X] : (pred(X) => (X = f("foo")))).
fof(exists_bar, axiom, pred(g("bar"))).
fof(f_not_g, axiom, ![X, Y] : f(X) != g(Y)).
```

I have tried throwing single quotes around, but I didn't find the proper way to do it.

How do I make syntactically different (composed) terms and test for syntactical equality?

Subsidiary question: the following program is satisfiable, because the automated-theorem prover understands `f` as a function rather than a uninterpreted functor.

```
fof(exists_f_g, axiom, (?[I] : ((f(foo) = f(I)) & pred(g(I))))).
fof(not_g_foo, axiom, ~pred(g(foo))).
```

To make it unsatisfiable, I need to manually specify that f is injective. What would be the natural way to obtain this behaviour without specifying injectivity of all functors that occur in my program?

```
fof(exists_f_g, axiom, (?[I] : ((f(foo) = f(I)) & pred(g(I))))).
fof(not_g_foo, axiom, ~pred(g(foo))).
fof(f_injective, axiom, ![X,Y] : (f(X) = f(Y) => (X = Y))).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all let me point you to the [Syntax BNF](http://www.cs.miami.edu/~tptp/TPTP/SyntaxBNF.html) of TPTP. In principle, you have Prolog terms with some predefined infix/prefix operators of appropriate precedences. This means, variables are written in upper case and constants are written in lower case. Also like Prolog, escaping with single quotes allows us to write a constant starting with a capital letter i.e. 'X'. I have never seen double quoted atoms so far, so you might want look up the instructions of the prover on how to interpret them.

But even though the syntax is Prolog-ish, automated theorem proving is a different kind of beast. There is no closed world assumption nor are different constants assumed to be different - that's why you cannot find a proof for:

```
fof(c1, conjecture, a=b ).
```

and neither for:

```
fof(c1, conjecture, ~(a=b) ).
```

So if you want to have syntactic dis-equality, you need to axiomatize it. Now, assuming a different from b trivially shows that they are different, so I at least claimed: "Suppose there are two different constants a and b, then there exists some variable which is not b."

```
fof(a1, axiom, ~(a=b)).
fof(c1, conjecture, ?[X]: ~(X=b)).
```

Since functions in first-order logic are not necessarily injective, you also don't get around of adding your assumption in there.

Please also note the different roles of input formulas: so far you only stated axioms and no conjectures i.e. you ask the prover to show your axiom set to be inconsistent. Some provers might even give up because they use some resolution refinements (e.g. set of support) which restricts resolution between axioms[1]. In any case, you need to be aware that the formula you are trying to prove is of the form `A1 ∧ ... ∧ An → C1 ∨ ... Cm` where the A are axioms and the C are conjectures.[2]

I hope that at least the syntax is a bit clearer now - unfortunately the answer to the questions is more that atomated theorem provers don't make the same assumptions as you expect, so you have to axiomatize them. These axiomatizations are also often ineffective and you might get better perfomance from specialized tools.

[1] As you already notice, advanced provers like Vampire or E Prover tell you about (counter-)satisfyability instead.

[2] A resolution based theorem prover will first negate that formula and perform a CNF transformation, but even though most TPTP accepting provers are resolution based, that's not a requirement.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it a bit. For double quotes, I heard about them from the [techincal report](http://www.cs.miami.edu/~tptp/TPTP/TR/TPTPTR.shtml#FormulaeSection) (that was also the part that had me believe there might have been a way to write down unequal term through syntax and without axiomatizing the unique name assumption and the injectivity).

Also, it seems that specifying multiple conjectures at once is deprecated, but I can certainly reformulate my problem to make my conjecture explicit.

Comment: I just checked the support of double quotes with E 1.8 and SPASS 4.6 -- both can read the term ```fof(c1, conjecture, ~ ("a" = "b") ).``` but only E refutes it. The tptp2dfg tool in the SPASS suite just creates different constants for "a" and "b" but does not add the difference axiom. The problem with multiple conjectures was that the specification required to prove their conjunction but some provers prove the disjunction. Which leads a bit to a general comment: the TPTP format is a superset of the language supported by the different provers (e.g. $ite ), so better double-check in the manual.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been SPASS 3.7 - I always confuse the version numbers.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Thanks for highlighting that TPTP is a superset of the supported language. I hadn't really thought about it this way.